# Tap on ion-delete-button triggers tap on list item too

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a list with onHold and onTap listeners. The onHold event triggers the ion-delete-button to appear. If I tap on the delete button the onTap event will be executed as well. How can I avoid this? Is this an ionic bug?

Example:

```
[http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBgrkW][1]
```

Comment: did you have try this on device?

Comment: Yes. It has the same effect on the device.

Comment: Ok. You have `onHold` event the trigger the delete button. When you tap on `deleteButton` you have the function called `onDelete`. When you tap in the `ion-item` you have the function `onTap`. Try to change `on-tap` to `ng-click`

Comment: PS: On codepen work perfectly. When i tap on item → onTap and when i tap on delete → onDelete (without fire onTap)

Comment: For me it doesnt work :-)